# AWS lambda doesn't recognize python modules in deployment package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I upload a (zipped) deployment package as a lambda function on AWS I get "no module named..." errors for both bs4 and google.

I created a virtual environment using venv and I installed the required dependencies
The app works fine when running from within the virtual environment. But, when I zip it up and upload it as a lambda function on AWS, I get "no module named..." errors for both "bs4" and (if I hash out the import of bs4 for debug reasons) also for "google".  I checked the site-packages folder in the zip file and they seem to be there.

Why is AWS saying there is no module when there is?!

I am using python3.6 on Ubuntu.

Comment: This seems interesting. I had a makefile that would package all the content in my venv and upload it to Lambda. Can you share a screen/directory listing of your ZIP Folder?

Comment: It is a very long tree and I am struggling to export it to anything other than the terminal. What to do ? :-( Could I send you the zip file?

Comment: Oke let me screenshot you the absolute basics u would need in ur ZIP for ur lambda to be able to recognize everything properly

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6FZk3Qm
Here is a screen of what my working ZIP Looks like. `1` is the list of installed python modules. `2` is my main python code. Everything else is default python libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda needs ZIP with all the libraries and your main python code file in the same folder. 
Here is what i do:

1. Create a new package folder with the following hierarchy

   `mkdir -p ./package/tmp/lib`
2. Copy Project folder into the temp folder

   `cp -a ./$(PROJECT)/. ./package/tmp/`
3. Copy python site-packages from virtual env to temp folder in package

   `cp -a $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/`
4. Remove any unused libraries (that are not required for this particular lambda to run) from temp folder

   ```
   rm -rf ./package/tmp/wheel*
   ```
5. Zip the temp package directory

   `cd ./package/tmp && zip -r ../$(PROJECT).zip .`

This final zip so created is ready for upload on Lambda.

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much. I'll try that later today.

Comment: Update - I havent yet got the Lambda running successfully as I have encountered another problem - but it seems to be as simple as moving all the site packages to the same folder as the scripts and zipping up.

Comment: yes,  ideally all site packages should be in ur script library. What issue are u facing now?

Comment: One of the python modules I am using (googlesearch) wants to write to disk and AWS Lambda only allows writing to /tmp.

Comment: Oh yes, that is a completely different problem. I would suggest you close this question, and ask a seperate question on it. As a hint, i would suggest you look into "S3" storage provided by AWs. i think it would solve ur problem perfectly. Make a new question and if i see i'll respond to that. As for the scope of this one, i feel the problem of Lambda not recognizing ur python libraries is solved.

Comment: Yes -thanks for your help. Actually I integrated all the scripts into one. Problem solved.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem. This closes the problem for any one asking the same question.